# Custom ArrayAdapter shows only 1 JSON item repeatedly

Tags: android, json, listview, android-arrayadapter, getview

I'm working on a messaging screen in our Android app that uses a custom ArrayAdapter, so that the messages sent between members will be laid out to look like chat bubbles. The data gets downloaded during onCreate(), and the JSON is parsed and loaded into the adapter, one message at a time, in onPostExecute(). The logs confirm this part.

The adapter gets loaded into a listView that sits above an EditText field and a Send button for new messages. Here is the fragment java, which includes the modified ArrayAdapter class, and the two XML files for the UI and the message row layout.

```java
package com.davepeyton.android.seekbromance;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/*
 * This fragment displays a simple list view using a custom array adapter, with a TextEdit
 * field for sending new messages.
 *
 * The layout 'dresses up' the messages (of class BroChatMsg) to look like chat balloons.
 */

public class BrofileBroChatFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String EXTRA_BROFILE_ID = "com.davepeyton.android.seekbromance.brofile_id";
    // no need to fetch the whole brofile here - it doesn't get displayed or altered
    // private static final String url_fetch_brofile = "http://www.seekbromance.com/android_connx/fetch_brofile.php";
    private static final String url_fetch_messages = "http://www.seekbromance.com/android_connx/fetch_messages.php";

    private int mCurrUserMemberId; // the member ID for the logged-in user
    // private String brofile_id; // parameter for fetch_brofile.php

    private int mConnectFailed = 0; // for HTTP exceptions and the like

    int brofileId;

    // parameters for fetch_message.php
    private String sender_id = "19";
    private String receiver_id = "2905";
    private int sid;
    private int rid;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // JSON node names to be used in this fragment
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGES = "messages";
    private static final String TAG_SID = "sid";
    private static final String TAG_RID = "rid";
    private static final String TAG_BODY = "body";
    private static final String TAG_TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";

    private static BroChatMsg sBroChatMsg;
    private ArrayList<BroChatMsg> mRetrievedMessages; // originally took the message data, now used only to initialize the adapter.
    private MessageAdapter mAdapter;

    private String mQuickString = "";

    private EditText mNewMsgField;
    private Button mSendMessageBtn;
    private ListView mLv;

    private String newMessageBody = "";


    public static BrofileBroChatFragment newInstance(int brofileId) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(EXTRA_BROFILE_ID, brofileId);

        BrofileBroChatFragment fragment = new BrofileBroChatFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);

        //Will probably need these later to get back to calling intent
        // get the ID of the Brofile to display from the calling intent
        brofileId = getArguments().getInt(EXTRA_BROFILE_ID);
        mCurrUserMemberId = 19; // quick set for testing


        //mCurrUserBrofileId = 25;  // this is a "full" dummy profile in the SB database; used for testing*/

        sBroChatMsg = new BroChatMsg();
        mRetrievedMessages = new ArrayList<BroChatMsg>();
        mAdapter = new MessageAdapter(mRetrievedMessages);

        //sid 19 and rid 2905 are for testing
        sid = 19;
        rid = 2905;
        sender_id = String.valueOf(sid);
        receiver_id = String.valueOf(rid);

        String logMsg = "Requesting sid = " + sender_id + " receiver_id = " + receiver_id;
        Log.d("Actions OnCreate", logMsg);

        new FetchMessages().execute();
    }

    class FetchMessages extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... strings) {
            JSONObject json = null;

            // Set up parameters for the PHP
            List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id1", sender_id));
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id2", receiver_id));

            // Make the HTTP request
            json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_fetch_messages, "GET", parameters);

            // Log the JSON response
            Log.d("Single Message Details", json.toString());

            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject messagesStuff) {

            int success = 0; // JSON Success tag
            JSONArray messagesArray = null;
            JSONObject message = null;
            BroChatMsg broChatMsgObj = new BroChatMsg();
            // ArrayList<BroChatMsg> messagesList = new ArrayList<BroChatMsg>(); (use the adapter instead)
            long timestamp;
            String msgDate;

            try {
                success = messagesStuff.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (success == 1) {

                try {
                    messagesArray = messagesStuff.getJSONArray(TAG_MESSAGES);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mAdapter.clear();

                for (int i = 0; i < messagesArray.length(); i++) {

                    //Populate the broChat object
                    try {

                        message = messagesArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        mQuickString = message.getString(TAG_SID);
                        broChatMsgObj.setSenderId(mQuickString);

                        mQuickString = message.getString(TAG_RID);
                        broChatMsgObj.setReceiverId(mQuickString);

                        mQuickString = message.getString(TAG_BODY);
                        mQuickString = mQuickString.replaceAll("\\r\\n", "");
                        broChatMsgObj.setMsgBody(mQuickString);

                        mQuickString = message.getString(TAG_TIMESTAMP);
                        broChatMsgObj.setTimestampStr(mQuickString);

                        timestamp = Long.valueOf(mQuickString) * 1000; //Used to format date
                        broChatMsgObj.setTimestamp(timestamp);

                        Date msgTime = new Date(timestamp);
                        broChatMsgObj.setMsgTime(msgTime);

                        msgDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy h:mm a").format(msgTime);
                        broChatMsgObj.setMsgDate(msgDate);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    sBroChatMsg = broChatMsgObj;

                    Log.d("sBroChat Message: ", String.valueOf(i));
                    Log.d("sBroChat SID ", sBroChatMsg.getSenderId());
                    Log.d("sBroChat RID ", sBroChatMsg.getReceiverId());
                    Log.d("sBroChat BODY ", sBroChatMsg.getMsgBody());
                    Log.d("sBroChat TIMESTAMP ", sBroChatMsg.getMsgDate());

                    mAdapter.add(sBroChatMsg);
                    // mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    // mRetrievedMessages.add(broChatMsgObj);

                    /* This is pretty much redundant.
                    for (i = 0; i < mRetrievedMessages.size(); i++) {
                        Log.d("message ", String.valueOf(i));
                        Log.d("message ", mRetrievedMessages.get(i).getId().toString());
                        Log.d("message TIMESTAMP ", mRetrievedMessages.get(i).getMsgDate());
                        Log.d("message SID ", mRetrievedMessages.get(i).getSenderId());
                        Log.d("message RID ", mRetrievedMessages.get(i).getReceiverId());
                        Log.d("message BODY ", mRetrievedMessages.get(i).getMsgBody());
                    }
                    */

                } // end message parsing

                // sBroChat.setMessages(mRetrievedMessages); (no longer used)

                // refresh the list view
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } else {
                // no matching messages turned up
                try {
                    mQuickString = messagesStuff.getString("message");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (mQuickString == "Connection error") {
                    mConnectFailed = 1;
                }
            }

            // return control to the main fragment
            // onFetchBrofileTaskComplete.setFetchBrofileTaskComplete();
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.brochat_fragment, container, false);
        /* This View holds the list and an edit window for new messages.

        NOTE!: Nothing from the list is being inflated here! The adapter does all that.
         */

        mLv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        mLv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mLv.setEmptyView(v.findViewById(R.id.emptyElement));


        mNewMsgField = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        mNewMsgField.setText(newMessageBody);
        mNewMsgField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence c, int start, int before, int count) {
                newMessageBody = c.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence c, int start, int count, int after) {
                // This method intentionally left blank
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable c) {
                // This one too
            }
        });

        mSendMessageBtn = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.new_chat_msg_button);
        mSendMessageBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO: Prepare new message, check sending privilege, send if allowed.
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    private class MessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BroChatMsg> {

        public MessageAdapter (ArrayList<BroChatMsg> chatter) {
            super(getActivity(), 0, chatter);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Displays one item at "position"
            boolean isLoggedUser = false;   // determines whether to show chat bubble on left or right
            boolean hasPrevious = false;    // false if this balloon is the oldest message

            String dateStr = "";
            BroChatMsg last_bcm = new BroChatMsg();
            long prevTimeStamp = 0;

            // If we weren't given a view, inflate one
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_brochat, null);
            }

            // Configure the view for this message
            BroChatMsg bcm = getItem(position);
            if (position > 0) { hasPrevious = true; }
            if (hasPrevious) { last_bcm = getItem(position - 1); }
            if (bcm.getSid() == mCurrUserMemberId) {isLoggedUser = true; }
            Date itemDate = bcm.getMsgTime();
            long itemTimestamp = bcm.getTimestamp();
            dateStr = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM dd, h:mm a").format(itemDate);
            // don't print date if under 5 minutes since last message
            if (hasPrevious) {
                prevTimeStamp = last_bcm.getTimestamp();
                if ((itemTimestamp - prevTimeStamp) < 600000) { dateStr = "";}
            }
            TextView MsgTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
            TextView DateTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.timelabel);
            LinearLayout wrapper = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.wrapper);

            MsgTextView.setText(bcm.getMsgBody());
            DateTextView.setText(dateStr);
            MsgTextView.setBackgroundResource(isLoggedUser ? R.drawable.bubble_yellow : R.drawable.bubble_green);
            wrapper.setGravity(isLoggedUser ? Gravity.LEFT : Gravity.RIGHT);

            return convertView;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (mConnectFailed == 1) {
            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            CantConnectDialogFragment connectDialog = new CantConnectDialogFragment();
            connectDialog.show(fm, "Not connected");
        }
    }


}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/form"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyElement"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="No messages"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/new_chat_msg_button"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/new_chat_msg_button" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send"
            android:id="@+id/new_chat_msg_button"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/form"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyElement"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="No messages"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/new_chat_msg_button"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/new_chat_msg_button" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send"
            android:id="@+id/new_chat_msg_button"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Currently, the correct **number** of downloaded messages gets displayed, but they are all duplicates of the last item retrieved from the JSON structure. As far as I can tell, the XML layout is not the culprit. What's happening to the rest of the messages being retrieved?

Comment: Please post picture of what it is doing as well

Comment: I also don't see the brochatmsg class

Comment: Also, please label the layouts

Comment: The BroChatMsg class doesn't contain much: just the sender/receiver IDs, message body, and time stamp.

Answer (score 0):

It happens becuase in your cycle you are using the same instance `broChatMsgObj`.
So all items are referring to the last value of the same object.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < messagesArray.length(); i++) {

          //You have to create a new object
          broChatMsgObj = new BroChatMsg();

          //Populate the broChat object
          try {

                 message = messagesArray.getJSONObject(i);

                 mQuickString = message.getString(TAG_SID);
                 broChatMsgObj.setSenderId(mQuickString);
                 //....
              }

         //....
    }
```

Comment: You nailed it: many thanks. But I'm still curious as to why sBroChat always shows the correct value but never managed to change the data in the adapter.

Comment: @BrogrammerDude Not sure about your question. You are calling mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); It is enough to change the data in the adapter.